# How to access my modules in Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

New to Zend!!

I have created a Zend projects with 2 modules, 1.defaule and 2.test

**Structure**

> application +
>            |__ Modules
>                  |**_default
>                         controllers
>                             IndexController.php
>                             ErrorController.php
>
>                         models
>                         views
>                  |**_test
>                         controllers
>                              IndexController.php
>                         models
>                         views

**application.ini**

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = "test"
```

Finally in my **test/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
class Test_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "This is Test Index Controller";
    }


}
```

I can access default module with no problems, but when I try

***dev.local/test/index***

It says **Application Error**

Any Suggestions why its doing this??

Comment: if you create another action inside of your index controller are you able to access that? Set up `public function mainAction() { echo 'hello'; }` then try to navigate to that controller.  If you can't, you probably have a mod_rewrite issue

Comment: did you try to see what the real error? resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0 make it to 1 this may give you the error

Comment: @Thanu Awesome I can see the error now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make

```
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

It will give you the exact error message in the controller, and whats in your views directory in your test module? You need to have a script template file for index action. Just guessing, coz faced similar issue recently.

Comment: Yep thats what it is… This is the exact error Message: script 'index/index.phtml' not found in path (/Development/test-dev/application/modules/test/views/scripts/)